# Windbg load symbol at address which is a reload module, symbol name can not be displayed

Tags: symbols, windbg, reload

I've wrote some pieces of code which is used to reload a PE module into arbitrary address, and below is the memory that the code reload `ntoskrnl.exe` of windows kernel:

```
kd> lm
start    end        module name
83c14000 84018000   nt         (pdb symbols)          \\vboxsvr\symbols\ntkrnlmp.pdb\00625D7D36754CBEBA4533BA9A0F3FE22\ntkrnlmp.pdb
899e1000 899e1000   nt_ffffffff899e1000 T (pdb symbols)          \\vboxsvr\sharedfolder\nt.pdb
......
```

Address `0x83c14000` is the original `ntoskrnl.exe` and `0x899e1000` is the new loaded one, 2 addresses contains same binary data:

```
kd> dc 83c14000 L20
83c14000  00905a4d 00000003 00000004 0000ffff  MZ..............
83c14010  000000b8 00000000 00000040 00000000  ........@.......
83c14020  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
83c14030  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000278  ............x...
83c14040  0eba1f0e cd09b400 4c01b821 685421cd  ........!..L.!Th
83c14050  70207369 72676f72 63206d61 6f6e6e61  is program canno
83c14060  65622074 6e757220 206e6920 20534f44  t be run in DOS 
83c14070  65646f6d 0a0d0d2e 00000024 00000000  mode....$.......
kd> dc 899e1000 L20
899e1000  00905a4d 00000003 00000004 0000ffff  MZ..............
899e1010  000000b8 00000000 00000040 00000000  ........@.......
899e1020  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
899e1030  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000278  ............x...
899e1040  0eba1f0e cd09b400 4c01b821 685421cd  ........!..L.!Th
899e1050  70207369 72676f72 63206d61 6f6e6e61  is program canno
899e1060  65622074 6e757220 206e6920 20534f44  t be run in DOS 
899e1070  65646f6d 0a0d0d2e 00000024 00000000  mode....$.......
```

The `\\vboxsvr\symbols\ntkrnlmp.pdb\00625D7D36754CBEBA4533BA9A0F3FE22\ntkrnlmp.pdb` and `\\vboxsvr\sharedfolder\nt.pdb` are same file, I just copied it into two difference places in order to use it.

**The prolbem is**: the reload kernel can not display correct symbol names.

Here is the evidence.

Show original `ZwCreateFile` codes:

```
kd> u ZwCreateFile L5
nt!ZwCreateFile:
83c47300 b842000000      mov     eax,42h
83c47305 8d542404        lea     edx,[esp+4]
83c47309 9c              pushfd
83c4730a 6a08            push    8
83c4730c e86d230000      call    nt!KiSystemService (83c4967e)
```

Which seems all good, then I caculated the offset of this function:

```
kd> ?83c47300-83c14000  // original function offset in ntoskrnl.exe
Evaluate expression: 209664 = 00033300
kd> ?899e1000+00033300  // function address in reloaded ntoskrnl.exe (0x899e1000 is new base address, see above)
Evaluate expression: -1985920256 = 89a14300
```

Check the "new" function at 0x89a14300:

```
kd> u 89a14300 L5
ReadVirtual: 89a14300 not properly sign extended
89a14300 b842000000      mov     eax,42h
89a14305 8d542404        lea     edx,[esp+4]
89a14309 9c              pushfd
89a1430a 6a08            push    8
89a1430c e86d230000      call    89a1667e
```

They have same OP code, except the call instruction. Original displayed with correct symbolic name `nt!KiSystemService` but the new reloaded one is not (just displayed a raw adress).

I caculated the offset again:

```
kd> ?83c4967e-83c14000
Evaluate expression: 218750 = 0003567e
kd> ?89a1667e-899e1000
Evaluate expression: 218750 = 0003567e
```

The call instruction's offset is equal.

**What am I wrong ? I want the reloaded module displays with correct symbolic name ...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic is hidden here:

```
kd> lm
start    end        module name
83c14000 84018000   nt         (pdb symbols)          \\vboxsvr\symbols\ntkrnlmp.pdb\00625D7D36754CBEBA4533BA9A0F3FE22\ntkrnlmp.pdb
899e1000 899e1000   nt_ffffffff899e1000 T (pdb symbols)          \\vboxsvr\sharedfolder\nt.pdb
......
```

Original nt module end address is `84018000`, but the new loaded module's end address qeuals its start address, so we need reload new module with this command:

```
.reload /i nt=899e1000,404000
```

After we indicated the correct size of new loaded module, all symbols worked:

```
kd> lmol
start    end        module name
83c14000 84018000   nt         (pdb symbols)          \\vboxsvr\sharedfolder\ntkrnlmp.pdb
899e1000 89de5000   ntkrnlmp   (pdb symbols)          \\vboxsvr\sharedfolder\ntkrnlmp.pdb
92cb8000 92cfb000   petool     (private pdb symbols)  x:\test\petool\build\objchk_win7_x86\i386\petool.pdb
kd> u nt!ZwCreateFile L5
nt!ZwCreateFile:
83c47300 b842000000      mov     eax,42h
83c47305 8d542404        lea     edx,[esp+4]
83c47309 9c              pushfd
83c4730a 6a08            push    8
83c4730c e86d230000      call    nt!KiSystemService (83c4967e)
kd> ?83c47300-83c14000+899e1000
Evaluate expression: -1985920256 = 89a14300
kd> u 89a14300 L5
89a14300 b842000000      mov     eax,42h
89a14305 8d542404        lea     edx,[esp+4]
89a14309 9c              pushfd
89a1430a 6a08            push    8
89a1430c e86d230000      call    ntkrnlmp!KiSystemService (89a1667e)
kd> u ntkrnlmp!ZwCreateFile L5
ntkrnlmp!ZwCreateFile:
89a14300 b842000000      mov     eax,42h
89a14305 8d542404        lea     edx,[esp+4]
89a14309 9c              pushfd
89a1430a 6a08            push    8
89a1430c e86d230000      call    ntkrnlmp!KiSystemService (89a1667e)
```